# How can I make sure that an included subproject runs before the main project in Gradle?

Tags: java, build, gradle

I have two Gradle projects with the following directory structure:

```
/baseDir
  /first
  /first/build.gradle
  /second 
  /second/build.gradle
  /second/settings.gradle
```

settings.gradle looks like this:

```
includeFlat "first"
```

When I do `gradle build` the second project is compiled after the first (main) project. I tried in the first project's build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
  compile project(':first')
}
```

When doing `gradle build` I get an error that dependencies declared in the first project could not be found in the second one.

What I need is the following. When I do `gradle build`on the second project I want that the first project will be build first and that `first.jar` is used as a dependency in the second project.

**How can I do that?**

Edit: When I set the following in my second project's settings.gradle:

```
includeFlat "first", "second"
```

then I get the following error while doing `graddle clean`:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not select the default project for this build. Multiple projects in this build have project directory '/Users/mg/Documents/Grails/GGTS3.6.3-SR1/second': [:, :second]
> Multiple projects in this build have project directory '/Users/mg/Documents/Grails/GGTS3.6.3-SR1/second': [:, :second]

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Edit: I create a sample project form demonstration: https://github.com/confile/Gradle-MultiProject-Test

Answer (score 2):

you can let the build task depend on the build task of another project:

```
build{
    dependsOn ':first:build'
}
```

Try this project settup:

```
root
  settings.gradle
  gradle.build
  first
    gradle.build
  second
    gradle.build
```

and put this in settings.gradle of your root:

```
include 'first'
include 'second'
```

Comment: And how can I use classes defined in the first project? I tried you idea in eclipse but it was not able to resolve the dependency of a class from first.

Comment: so whats your exact error ? you cant import the class ? But the project builds ?

Comment: The projects are build. But in eclipse the sources of first are not available in second. They could not be resolved. So I guess I have to put them somehow on the source path of second.

Comment: are the classes of your first project in the default package or in no package ? try putting them in one

Comment: The classes are on ``org.test``.

Comment: compile project(':first') is this in your /second/gradle.build right?

Comment: yes compile project(':first') is in second dependencies { }

Comment: i can import the "Person" class in Second's "Some"without problems. Im using Intellij Idea 14 tho..

Comment: Your are right but still I cannot do ``compile project(':First')``without importing all the dependencies of First.

Comment: what to do If I want to create a jar of the whole project

Answer (score 0):

You should move the block

```
dependencies {
  compile project(':first')
}
```

to the second project's build.gradle.
This will build the first project and before the second project and second project could use first project's classes.

Comment: This is what I did. I wrote this in my question.

Comment: Have you try to add second project in your settings.gradle ?

Comment: I cannot add the second project to the settings.gradle of the second project. This gives an error.

Comment: could you post the error  message ?
Do you have the following content in your settings.gradle : include 'first','second'  ?

Comment: You need a settings.gradle in your baseDir , it must contains
include (or includeFlat) 'first','second'. 
first/settings.gradle and second/settings.gradle must not contains include in your case.

Comment: Well this could not work because I need to tell the second project that there must be first included

Comment: no second doesnt need to know that first is included. It just needs to know which dependencies it has.

Comment: You could look a section 57.7 here [Gradle multiproject configuration](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html)

Comment: @seb-c I created a sample here: https://github.com/confile/Gradle-MultiProject-Test

Comment: In fact your gradle settings are right.
You have a problem with transitive dependencies : you use some libraries in the First/lib directory which is not seen by Second project.
Add the following to Second/build.gradle : repositories {
  flatDir {
    dirs '../First/lib'
  }
}
and it will work.

Answer (score -1):

```
dependencies {
  implementation files( project(‘:first’).tasks.jar )
}
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Comment: you may also ask AI assistant to generate 400 words essay if you want;-)))

Comment: No, that would not be a good idea here: [Temporary policy: Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned)  Any explanations of code should be written in your own words without AI assistance.  Much of the time AI gets such explanations plain wrong.

Comment: if code is confusing to you, local bakery might help